# JSF 1.2 JSP 2.0 Simple Custom Tag File with Attributes

Tags: file, jsp, jsf, attributes, tags

So I'm trying to do a custom tag in a JSF 1.2 environment with JSP 2.0. I'm ultimately trying to pass a java Object as an attribute with EL, but I was getting a "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: jsp.error.beans.property.conversion" exception. So I took a step back and tried to just get a simple custom tag to work. I was successful in printing hello world. I then tried to pass it a simple String attribute and just print that. This was not working. The attribute would not print to the screen. The static "hello world" text does just not the attribute.

WEB-INF/tags/helloworld.tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jsp:root version="2.0" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:ui="http://www.sun.com/web/ui" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="message" required="true"/>
  <ui:staticText id="asdf" text="hello world: #{message}"/>
</jsp:root>
```

MyBean.jsp then defines the tag namespace: xmlns:tags="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags" and then calls the tag like so:

```
<tags:helloworld message="Test message"/>
```

I am using jboss 4.0.4 to deploy the war file.

Comment: @Sam: it's fine that you put a bounty on this, but are you absolutely positive that you've **exactly** the same problem as the OP? The `xmlns:ui="http://www.sun.com/web/ui"` in OP's snippet indicates that he's using the awkward [Woodstock](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/woodstock/info) component library which died ages ago. This was for me (and most likely also many others) the reason to ignore this question as I know nothing about it.

Comment: @BalusC, Ah, I probably have a different problem then.

Comment: Did you try to show this message attribute in different ways and it did not work ? or is it just <ui:staticText> ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set rtexprvalue="true" in "message" attribute ie:

```
<jsp:directive.attribute name="message" required="true" rtexprvalue="true"/>
```